# How to map E.164 Telephone Number to DNS name using ENUM protocol in java?

Tags: java

I am currently working  on a java application to map the E.164 Telephone Number to DNS name to get a IP address.I dont know how to do this.If any body knows it please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping part is really simple,

```
                    public String getEnum(String number) {
                            String data = number.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
                            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                            for (int i = data.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
                            {
                                    sb.append(data.charAt(i)).append('.');
                            }
                            sb.append("e164.arpa.");
                            return sb.toString();
                    }
```

Comment: Ok fine.After getting this string which is called as  DNS query String ,using this i have to get the DNS name corresponding to that phone number.how i can do this?

Comment: This is the DNS name that you can use to do DNS lookup. I guess you need to get the NAPTR record for SIP URI etc. Java doesn't support that. You will need to use Java DNS package http://www.dnsjava.org/ for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I got some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too complicated. Here's an extract from the corresponding [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_mapping):

> The ITU ENUM allocates a specific
>   zone, namely "e164.arpa" for use with
>   ENUM E.164 numbers on the IP side of
>   the network. RFC 3761 define how any
>   ENUM number, such as +1 555 42 42 can
>   be transformed into a URI, by
>   reversing the numbers, separating them
>   with dots and adding the e164.arpa
>   suffix thus: 2.4.2.4.5.5.5.1.e164.arpa

**Edit**

Just in detail:

1. read the phone number as a
   String (or convert it to a string)
2. remove any char that is not a
       number (whitechars, '+', etc)
3. revert the string, in this case: 15554242 -> 24245551
4. put a dot
   behind each number, here: 24245551
   -> 2.4.2.4.5.5.5.1.
5. append 'e164.arpa'

that's all - you don't need special API, it's just a sort of String transformation

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Theoretically it is ok but i want to implement this concept in java.Like My application has to get a phone number as input and give corresponding IP address as output.This is what i want to do.I read in some article like JSR-161 api is used to do this.But i am struggling to get that api.If any know the link please tell me.